# Why chkdsk showing windows found no problems?

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

See I scan my disk with chkdsk, why it still shows windows found no problems, 
even it clearly contains 12kb in bad sectors?
[image]

Comment: The disk won't use any sectors already marked as bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chkdsk checks the **file system** for errors, **not the disk itself**. It can be used to check for bad sectors but this is rudimentary and inferior to using actual disk maintenance and monitoring software

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK):

> CHKDSK (short for "check disk") is a system tool in DOS, OS/2 and
>   Windows. It verifies the file system integrity of a volume and fixes
>   logical file system errors. It is similar to the fsck command in Unix

.

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question - "why it still shows windows found no problems, even it clearly contains 12kb in bad sectors?

Comment: @DavidPostill It answers the question "why it still shows windows found no problems, even it clearly contains 12kb in bad sectors" because this tool (CHKDSK) checks the file system for errors, not the disk itself! And the file system is OK! BTW, bad sectors are just a reality of hard disks, and there’s generally no reason to panic when you encounter one.